# transition rates from transition probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

Let $(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb Z}$ be a homogeneous Markov chain on some state space $S$ with transition prbabilities $P=[P_{ij}]_{i,j\in S}$. The law $p_i(t):=\mathbb P(X_{t}=i)$ of $X_t$ satisfies:
\begin{equation}
p_i(t+1)=\sum_{j\in S}\mathbb P(\;X_{t+1}=i\;|\;X_t=j\;)\;p_j(t)=\sum_{j\in S}P_{ij}\;p_j(t)
\end{equation}
What is the best approximating rate equation for this?
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\tilde p_i(t)=(W\cdot \tilde p(t))_i\;
\end{equation}
i.e. what is $W$ in terms of $P$, such that the error between $p$ and $\tilde p$ is minimized? For instance I know that 
\begin{equation}
\tilde p(t+\Delta t)=\text{e}^{W\Delta t}\tilde p(t)
\end{equation}
Thus I need to solve $P=\text{e}^{W}$ for $\Delta t=1$, or in other words $W=\log P$. Is this exact, in the sense that $\tilde p(t)=p(t)$ for $t\in \mathbb Z$ when $W=\log P$?

Comment: Your W seems very familiar with the generating matrix(or Q-matrix) for a continous Markov Chain

Comment: Hi Patrick. Thanks! It is not only very similar to the generator of the continuous Markov process, but identical to it :)

Comment: Yes, if $P=e^W$ and $W$ is a Q-matrix then $\tilde p(n)=p(n)$ for every integer $n$. Note that the existence of the Q-matrix $W$ is not guaranteed. Which matrices $P$ are you considering?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really helpful. So the existence of $W$ is not guaranteed? That is shocking. Do you know of any example? For me that'd already be an answer that I would gladly accept :) Of course I have a particular $P$ in mind, but there are two reasons why I'd rather not state it: 1) I got around the issue in some other way. 2) It's a network dynamics where the state space is humongous. .... However if you'd really like to see it, I can post it. Let me know :)